# Is the union-closed sets conjecture open for the power sets case?

Tags: co.combinatorics

In a paper published by Bruhn and Schaudt, as well as in a [presentation](https://www.uni-ulm.de/fileadmin/website_uni_ulm/mawi.inst.081/Henning/unionclosedtalk.pdf) given by Bruhn, they point out how the union-closed sets conjecture is tight for power sets, implying it is still open.  I am confused however, as I have not come across any literature regarding the conjecture for power sets, so I am wondering if someone can elucidate why this is the case? Is it because the result is already proven for power sets?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

It is trivially true for power sets, since these are union-closed families with $2^n$ sets such that every element appears in exactly $2^{n-1}$ sets.

This is what they mean by the conjecture being tight - power sets show that the $1/2$ of the conjecture cannot be increased to any greater constant.